# Speed up for loop in python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I have a code snippet that generates a list of vectors for a optimization problem, but it takes to long time to run.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
import time

v=[35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46]


m=np.array(list(it.combinations_with_replacement(v,9)))
g=m[np.sum(m, axis=1)==360]
print('g shape',g.shape)

f=[]
for i,vector in enumerate(g[0:10]): #all vector is to be processed, but it takes tolong time
    print(i)
    start = time.time()
    unique_permutations = set(it.permutations(vector))
    end = time.time()
    print('length unique perm',len(unique_permutations))
    print('time perm',end-start)

    already_reviewed = []

    start= time.time()
    for p in list(unique_permutations):
        if p not in already_reviewed:       # a lot of time is spen in this check
            circular_permutations = [p[i:] + p[:i] for i in range(len(p))]
            already_reviewed.extend(circular_permutations)
            unique_permutations.difference_update(circular_permutations[1:])
    end=time.time()
    print('loop', end-start)       

    f.append(list(unique_permutations))
```

Would really much appreciate help.
Br Erik

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Why are you trying to realize, in memory, the complete set of permutations? You're using ridiculous amounts of memory with no real benefit AFAICT.

Comment: Are you aware that Python has a builtin ``set`` type?

Comment: `if p not in already_reviewed` - The `in` operator is much faster if the container is a `set` instead of a `list`.

Comment: I need help to speed up the code...
The permutations of 9 angles is a control signal for  a later process.

Comment: the length of the vector is 9, I only takes the vector that adds up to 360, and all rotational permutation is neglected. so its a big number, but not billions i hope...

Answer (score 0):

You are converting it.permutations(vector) to a set.

```
unique_permutations = set(it.permutations(vector))
```

Then you are converting it into a list in the below lines...

```
for p in list(unique_permutations):
```

I see the only reason you are not using it as a generator (which is probably how you should be using) is that you are trying to find the length as follows...

```
print('length unique perm',len(unique_permutations))
```

and another here...

```
unique_permutations.difference_update(circular_permutations[1:])
```

But this is already redundant with *already_reviewed* variable, they seem to do the same thing, you are performing some check twice.

So I don't see the use of unique_permutations variable other than getting its length (the difference_update part of the code is redundant), and I would just do...

```
unique_permutations = it.permutations(vector)
for p in unique_permutations:
    ...
...
```

PS: Also are you sure you are getting the desired results? Because I see you are converting generator to a set first, then to a list and then operating on the set and then converting it back to a list in every for a loop. Since a set is unordered, won't it give undesired results?

Sorry guys I don't have enough reputation to post it as a comment.